# Empty Visualforce tags without closing whitespace

Tags: visualforce

Consider this very simple part of a Visualforce Page:

```
<apex:variable var="object" value="{!MyObject__c}"/>
<apex:pageMessages/>
```

Until recently when you tried to save this you would've gotten this after a roundtrip to the server:

```
<apex:variable var="object" value="{!MyObject__c}" />
<apex:pageMessages />
```

Notice how a space was added before closing the tag. For some reason, this has now been changed to:

```
<apex:variable var="object" value="{!MyObject__c}"/>
<apex:pageMessages />
```

As you can see the `apex:pageMessages` retains/gains a space before the end of the tag while `apex:variable` will just save it "as is".

This suddenly changed behavior is causing a lot of unnecessary diffs when used in conjunction with the automatic formatting feature of IntelliJ /w Illuminated Cloud. Any ideas as to why this change occurred? Can anybody confirm this behavior?

It seems like every few months there is a change in how Visualforce pages are saved on the server which is incredibly annoying as it will cause a lot of unnecessary diffs in the repository. Most of it is happening in managed packages though so it shouldn't affect that many users. Still annoying as hell.

Comment: We are ignoring white space changes while checking diff

Comment: Thanks. Yes, this could be used as a last resort. But my question is: Why is this suddenly happening? I'm seeing this in every Org I'm in charge of.

Comment: When saving `<apex:pageMessages></apex:pageMessages>` from developer console, it saves as `<apex:pageMessages ></apex:pageMessages>`; so doesn't seems to be a problem with Intelli-j but visualforce engine in general. Also it does not matter even if we downgrade the version.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear about that. Yes - it is an error of Visualforce but it becomes more of a problem when used with some kind of source code formatting.

Comment: Okay - this is strange. I just tried it through the developer console as you did and it was working as expected. I'm really confused and need to investigate further.